# Oracle and ADO Query from Excel returns no results

Tags: oracle, vba, excel, excel-2010, ado

I am having trouble running a query in Excel 2010 VBA code using Oracle OraOLEDB.Oracle Provider.

Certain queries work fine and return results, while others return no results...

I connect as such:

```
 Set DBConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    DBConnection.Provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle"
    DBConnection.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    DBConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & TNSName & ";User Id=" & OraUserName & ";Password=" & OraPassWord & ";"
    DBConnection.Open
```

I then try to query:

```
command2.ActiveConnection = DBConnection
command2.CommandText = "SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3 FROM table(MySchema.MyPackage.MyFunction('Param1'))"
command2.CommandType = adCmdText

Set QueryRecordSet = New ADODB.Recordset
QueryRecordSet.LockType = adLockReadOnly
QueryRecordSet.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
QueryRecordSet.Open command2


command2.Execute
```

and I get nothing...any ideas?

If I run a simple query like

```
select * From my_table
```

it works fine...it seems joins or other more complex queries don't compile??

Additionally, selecting from views does not work.

```
select * from my_view
```

Returns nothing

Comment: I guess I should also note that the functions are in a package.

Comment: I have also come across lots of post about CTE's (with statement) not working with ADO. It would be great to hear from an ADO expert what is going here, why is the query not simply passed to the database?  what is ADO doing trying to parse this query?  And why does it fail silently?

Comment: Did you try `DBConnection.CursorLocation = adUseServer` ?

Comment: Probably error located in the code of `MySchema.MyPackage.MyFunction()`. Can you post exact code from this function? If not, try to place a simple code returning set of records instead of current function body and see whether the function return result set or not.

Comment: @ThinkJet - yes I tried every possible permutation of connection properties.  The function works perfectly if you call it from SQL...but sure I will post code later today.

Comment: You mean you can directly execute `SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3 FROM table(MySchema.MyPackage.MyFunction('Param1'))` in SQL without errors?

Comment: @sam092 yes. works fine in SQL.

Comment: Ok. Is query executed on a computer where VBA code runs?

Comment: yup, in fact, The query works fine if you use a DSN connection to Oracle with the ODBC driver...so it is something specific to this provider.

Comment: It's also a problem on 3 different computers, some running 64 bit excel and oracle drivers and other running 32 bit excel and oracle drivers...we have tested the odac tools for oracle 10 and 11 (latest version for each) and none have worked.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having a problem using OraOLEDB.Oracle with ADO.NET that sounds exactly like this!

Comment: nope. ODBC tends to be more reliable, but the OraOLEDB conundrum still exists.

Comment: I would be very suspicious that your parameter contains additional spaces or the wrong case and the result is no rows. This might be because of the driver or it might be because of the user accidentally putting it in, or if you are getting the value off an Excel sheet, that might also be the issue. Why don't you try the query at the bottom of this link to capture the actual SQL being submitted and verify whether it really returns rows or not. https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2349367

Comment: @ElectricLlama I confirmed it does return rows.  The only way I have been able to solve this problem is to use ODBC.  It is a shame that Oracle would release an improperly documented,tested, and functional driver.

Comment: ODBC just calls the Oracle driver. Did you manage to capture the actual query submitted? That's the only way to be certain of what is actually being submitted.

Comment: I grabbed the commandText property from the ADODB object directly before the execute command.  I did not attempt to listen on the Oracle side for any queries coming in.

Answer (score 2):

I'm putting this as an answer only because comment formatting doesn't allow me to add code.

Does the stored procedure work if you run it separately via the command object?

```
command2.CommandText = "MySchema.MyPackage.MyFunction"
command2.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
command2.Parameters.Refresh
command2.Parameters.Item(1).Value = "Param1"
command2.Execute
Debug.Print command2.Parameters.Item(0).Value
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is what you are looking for.  I was looking for another answer and I know this works for me.

```
    Set cmdSum = New adodb.Command

With cmdSum
    Set .ActiveConnection = oCon
    .Properties("PLSQLRSet") = True
    .CommandText = "{CALL StoredProc(?,?)}"
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, Format(CDate(sTerm), "mm/dd/yyyy"))
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, Format(CDate(sEff), "mm/dd/yyyy"))
End With

Set Rs = cmdSum.Execute()

For c = 0 To Rs.Fields.Count - 1
    Wk.Cells(3, c + 1) = Rs.Fields(c).Name
Next c
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here after an Excel ADO query to Oracle would not work.

Although it states in the questions' comments that you can use ODBC to work-around this, it took me a while to figure out how to get the ODBC connection string working.

Here is an ODBC connection to Oracle that I got working.

```
dbConn = "ODBC;Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;" & _
         "Data Source=odbc_connection_name;" & _
         "User Id=user_id;" & _
         "Password=user_pwd;" & _
         "DBQ=tns_name;"
```

`tns_name` is what you named your connection within the `tnsnames.ora` file.

`odbc_connection_name` is what you named your odbc connection.

Then you can just use this to connect to Oracle using ADO like normal:

```
cn.Open dbConn
cn.CommandTimeout = 1000
rs.Open sql, cn
```

Note I also had to increase the `CommandTimeout` property, as ODBC's default timeout is relatively short.